# Online version of R

Tags: javascript, php, r, web

I want to interact with R on a website. Passing some commands with JavaScript (or PHP), R does the computations and returns the results I then want to illustrate appropriately.

Is there an "online version" of R that can handle those requests?
I only found [r-node](https://github.com/elijah/r-node), but it seems to be outdated (last commits 5-6 years ago).

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: [google: r online - first result](http://www.r-fiddle.org)

Comment: @rawr This just allows me to run R code in their website, but I need to interact with that from my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can accomplish this with R-Studio server.

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

Comment: So in this case I need an own running server, where I need to install the software?

Comment: Yes, you would need to install this on your server. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Of course, if what you're looking for is just a place to play with some R code on somebody else's website, http://www.r-fiddle.org/ is literally the #1 Google result for "run R code online." Google is your friend.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a place to play around with R. As already mentioned, I need a web service, which just handles R requests from my website. I do have webspace, where I can upload HTML-files, but, unfortunately, I don't have a customizable server, where I can install RStudio server.